# Mousescroll scrolling 3 times

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mouseevent, mousewheel, numericupdown

When I scroll my mouse wheel in VB.Net "NumericUpAndDown", it scrolls 3x the value, I would like to scroll 1 time only...

After some searching, I found this

```
Public Sub RolagemMouse(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    ' Periocidade.MouseWheel, Parcelas_UP_DWN.MouseWheel, TB_Valor.MouseWheel
    Try
        If e.Delta > 0 Then
            sender.Value += sender.increment
        Else
            sender.Value -= sender.increment
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
    CType(e, HandledMouseEventArgs).Handled = True

End Sub
```

It solved my problem, but I've a lot of NumericUpAndDown in my forms, then I had another idea, in FormLoad event I added

```
For Each grupo As GroupBox In Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)
        For Each objeto As NumericUpDown In grupo.Controls.OfType(Of NumericUpDown)
            AddHandler objeto.MouseWheel, AddressOf RolagemMouse
        Next
    Next
```

But that's not practical, I've to put this in every form, is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple custom control, inheriting NumericUpDown, that overrides `OnMouseWheel` to apply the defined `Increment` value instead of the default [`SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.mousewheelscrolllines) (`=3`, usually) applied by the [UpDownBase](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UpDownBase.cs,31) class.

Note that the increment your code is currently adding to the Value, doesn't count the `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties, so you'll probably get an exception while incrementing or decrementing the `Value` property, since `Value` will be outside the accepted bounds, at some point.

`Public Sub New()` is there for a reason, even if it looks empty. If you decide to use it, don't cut it off.
In Visual Studio, you can substitute all existing NumericUpdown controls with the custom one, using the Search & Replace function (unless redefined, it can be *invoked* with <kbd>Control + H</kbd>).

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Forms

<DesignerCategory("Code")>
Public Class NumericUpDownEx
    Inherits NumericUpDown

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseWheel(e As MouseEventArgs)
        Dim newValue = Me.Value + Me.Increment * Math.Sign(e.Delta)
        Me.Value = Math.Max(Math.Min(newValue, Me.Maximum), Me.Minimum)
        DirectCast(e, HandledMouseEventArgs).Handled = True
        MyBase.OnMouseWheel(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```